# Which Security mechanism to be used while sending iPhone contacts to web server

Tags: ios, iphone, encryption, abaddressbook

I am creating app , in which i also need to display  All contacts and same app users like whatsapp.
and i have read somewhere we can't send directly contacts to server, instead we have to use some Secure Algorithm. 
What kind of encryption should i use?

Comment: The best you can afford. Why do you need the contact details, what will they be used for?

Comment: Because i need to send my all contacts to server , where i will match contacts with the registered user.

Comment: So you don't actually need to send the contact details, you could send a hash of the user e-mail or something like that...

Comment: why email?? actually my server is taking phone number as username for registration . so i can match only with phone number

Comment: That's fine, the same process can apply, so long as you always use the same source information you can just pass hashes and compare them to check if people know other people. The point is that by passing hashes you never need to send the actual phone number / e-mail address for any user.